# Can't compile RenderScript after updating to Android Studio 4.3 with build-tools 18.1.1

Tags: android, renderscript

I've been working on a RenderScript project for quite some time now, using older versions of Android Studio. I'm targeting 4.3 with SDK version 18.

I've had run-time issues when compiling the project with new **build-tools 19+** (crashes when I modify the root() 'uchar *v_out' parameter), so I decided to go back to build-tools 18.1.1. But when compiling with this version I get the error:

> 'conversion.rs error: Compute Kernel root() targeting SDK levels 11-13
>   may not skip parameters FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Execution failed for task :test:compileDebugRenderscript.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run
>   command:  C:\Program
>   Files\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\18.1.1\llvm-rs-cc.exe -O 3 -I
>   C:\Program
>   Files\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\18.1.1\renderscript\include\ -I
>   C:\Program
>   Files\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\18.1.1\renderscript\clang-include\
>   ...

Perhaps it's a problem with my **kernel function signature**? Even with a simple .rs file below, it fails to compile. I used to be able to compile and run this fine and I'm pretty sure it was using build-tools 18 back then..

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.app.test);

void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
This is getting strange... if I use gradle version 1.10 with build-tools 19.0.1, the code compiles but gives me the following error if i try to modify 'uchar4 *out'

> : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEV) Aat 0xdeadbaad (code=1)'

Answer (score 0):

Are you really targeting API levels 11-13 or is that part of the confusion? If you are looking to target those levels, you will need to update the root signature to include a "const void *usrData, size_t usrDataLen". You have to do this even if you are not using them, since the older API versions of RS don't let you skip these parameters. More modern versions of RS do let you skip parameters that you don't want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the odd thing, I'm not targeting API levels 11-13 - my build.gradle sets the target and min sdk version to 18, with build tools 18.1.1 and gradle 1.9. - I am able to compile the RS file if I use SDK 19 + build tools 19.0.1 (still targeting 4.3) but as soon as I set *out to an arbitrary number - I get SIGSEV as stated above.

Comment: Can you post more of the log before the SIGSEGV? What device/version are you running this on? There is an encoding bug in SDK 19 that we have fixed internally, but hasn't been released yet, and I believe that is what you are hitting now.

Comment: Update: Adding those two parameters (Tested at the start and end) causes the following error: Unexpected kernel root() parameter 'usrData' of type 'const void *' - same for the other parameter.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that those go before the "x" parameter. Put them after input, output.

Comment: Ok, so I ran it again with the latest build tools, sdk ect. Hopefully this is enough information: http://pastebin.com/17QeSp4f

Comment: So that log indicates that you are running on either Nexus10 or another ARM Mali-based device. It is failing to find the runtime library to link the code. Is this an AOSP build? Did you forget to add the vendor driver binary blobs?

Comment: Thanks, I should have added this is running on a stock Note 10.1 with (Samsung Exynos 5420 - Mali™-T628 MP6) running Android 4.3. (I also get the same error with the Note 3 Exynos edition) - This example runs on the Nexus 10 without error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that I can run the newer Kernel style with 'uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) test(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y);'But I specifically need access to the *out pointer.

Comment: I think that this is a bug that we fixed in AOSP, but hasn't made it to the SDK yet. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64775 is where we tracked it. Can you try an older version of the tools (or even maybe build your app using the AOSP build system, rather than the SDK itself)?